# Validate field depending on the value of another Angular

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I ask for your cooperation to indicate how I can validate a text field that depends on the value selected on a Radio button; Actually what I need is to activate the observations field only if option 4 is selected, but the form shows it as invalid.

When I select option four it tells me that it is required of the field observacionA, but when I fill it the form follows invalid

`Class`

```
export class AppComponent {

  testForm: FormGroup;
  msgError: string = 'Este Campo es obligatorio';

  opciones = [
    { nombre: 'N1', valor: 1 },
    { nombre: 'N2', valor: 2 },
    { nombre: 'N3', valor: 3 },
    { nombre: 'Otra Respuesta', valor: 4 },
  ];

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.testForm = this.fb.group({
      'opcionA': ['', [Validators.required]],
      'observacionA': new FormControl(null)
    }, {
        validator: this.specificValue
      });
  }

  valido(): boolean {
    return !this.testForm.valid;
  }

  specificValue(group: any) {
    if (!group.controls.opcionA || !group.controls.opcionA.value) return;

    const opcionA = group.controls.opcionA.value;
    let observacionA = group.controls.observacionA.value;
    if (opcionA == '4') {
      if (observacionA) {
        return {
          return: null
        };
      } else {
        return {
          isRequired: true
        };
      }
    }
  }

  guardar() {
    console.log(this.testForm.value);
  }

}
```

`Html`

```
<h1>Form</h1>

<form [formGroup]="testForm" (ngSubmit)="guardar()" novalidate>
  <label *ngFor="let opcion of opciones">
  <input type="radio" 
        formControlName="opcionA"
        required
        [value]="opcion.valor">{{opcion.nombre}}
</label>
  <div *ngIf="testForm.get('opcionA').invalid">
    {{ msgError }}
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="testForm.value.opcionA === 4">
    <textarea formControlName="observacionA"></textarea>
    <div *ngIf="testForm.get('observacionA').invalid">
      {{ msgError }}
    </div>
  </div>
<br>
<hr>
  <button [disabled]="valido"
          type="submit">
  Save
</button>
</form>

{{testForm.valid}}
```

[Demo in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggvo36?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Can you put this in plnkr or stackblitz?

Comment: ok, you can already see the demo of my app @brijmcq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When validator is valid you should return `null` not object like:

```
{
  return: null
}
```

It should be:

```
if(observacionA){
  return null;
```

One more note:

```
<button [disabled]="valido()"
                          ^^^
                     add this because it's method
```

**[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-npkvz9?file=app/app.component.html)**

Comment: how could you add validation to the field of observacionA @yurzui

Answer (score 0):

There may be many other solutions, But i think this is the simplest one.

**HTML :**

```
<md-radio-group formControlName="opcionA" required >
   <md-radio-button *ngFor="let opcion of opciones" (change)="validField=opcion.valor" [value]="opcion.valor" >
                    {{opcion.nombre}}
   </md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
<md-form-field *ngIf="(validField==4) ? true : false">
    <textarea mdInput
          formControlName="observacionA"
          [errorStateMatcher]="myErrorStateMatcher"
          >
    </textarea>
<md-error>{{ msgError }}</md-error>
```

**Typescript :**

```
 testForm: FormGroup;
 opciones = [
  { nombre: 'A', valor: 1 },
  { nombre: 'B', valor: 2 },
  { nombre: 'C', valor: 3 },
  { nombre: 'Otra Respuesta', valor: 4 },
 ];

validField:number; //declared variable for html
constructor (public fb: FormBuilder) { }
...
```

Hope this helps you.